# Call API in my android app via Google Assistant command

Tags: android, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk, google-home, google-assist-api

I am developing a android app where I want to call API using the Google Assistant. Like if user tells the google assistant "Hey google,ask my 'app name' whats my highest score for today?",i want to call one API from where I get highest score of the user and on API response send it to google assistant.

I have tried to do this using DialogFlow by calling static API where user id or authentication is not required.....But now what I want to do is,Call API from action where I will pass my application logged in userID to get user data

Comment: Google Assistant Actions "Ok Google, talk to xyz about abc" are normally considered cloud based functions/API/service and usually don't involve an Android app unless you are doing [Account Linking](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/) for multi-platform, but your question is unclear if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: I want to implement deep linking in android app though google assistant command like shown in https://developers.google.com/actions/app/

Comment: So is there no any call back for google assistance which you come to know that this has been done?

Comment: The Android-based actions only support a subset of capabilities as described in the documentation.